# Getting AWS API Gateway Request Id in backend api

Tags: docker, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-2.1, request-headers

We have setup of apis as below

```
Development : ASP NET Core 2.1 C#
Backend api deployment : In AWS through docker
Gateway : AWS API Gateway which contains custom lambda Authorizer
```

Requirement : To get the API Gateway request id in backend api for logging and request tracking.

As the request passes through the API gateway, it generates a request id. This is set in response header in "**x-amzn-RequestId**" by the gateway and can be visible in client (like postman). I could find that this id is also available in the lambda authorizer in the object of **APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest** - .**RequestContext.RequestId**, which I could use for the authorizer logging.

Now as the request is authorized, actual api is invoked. I want the same request id in this api for logging purpose. Eventually - to identify the journey of request through the gateway-aurhorizer-api having same request  and generate the stats.

In the api code, we have also implemented **OnActionExecuting()** of **APIControllerActionFilter**. I want to know if the gateway request id is available here by any means ? Or any way to pass the id from the gateway to the actual api ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In API Gateway console, you can add HTTP headers in the Integration Request section. So you can add a custom header and map it back to the requestId.

[image]

or in Mapping Templates you can do this

```
#set($context.requestOverride.header.requestId = $context.requestId)
```

This will then be passed downstream by API Gateway.

From a test using Beeceptor.com

[image]

Comment: Thanks @K Mo, this worked, just a little addition to the answer is - re deploy the API  from the AWS console to get this into effect. :)

Comment: relevant documentation on AWS is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP` version of the API Gateway appears to do this automatically.

The gateway generates the request ID and adds it to the request that is sent to the application.  It is transmitted via the `X-Request-ID` header.

Comment: I have printed all incoming request headers but did not find this header in ECS container spring-boot, but X-Amzn-Trace-Id